# Run multiple test using maven command with testing.xml

Tags: java, xml, maven

I am trying to run a multiple test on a single maven command.

testing.xml

```
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd" >

<suite name="Suite1" verbose="1">

    <test name="group1" parallel="false" preserve-order="true">
        <classes>
            <class name="apps.Test1" />
            <class name="apps.Test2" /> 
            <class name="apps.Test3" />
        </classes>
    </test>

    <test name="group2" parallel="false" preserve-order="true">
        <classes>
            <class name="apps.Test4" />
            <class name="apps.Test5" /> 
            <class name="apps.Test6" />
        </classes>
    </test>
</suite>
```

1. Run all test cases from testing.xml

   mvn -Dtests=testing.xml test

If i want to run test cases from group1 such as Test1, Test2, Test3. How can I do so ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need to edit your surefire config to support this as below :

```
<plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>yourversion</version>
            <configuration>
                    <skipTests>false</skipTests>
                    <suiteXmlFiles>
                        <suiteXmlFile>${suiteXmlFile}</suiteXmlFile>
                    </suiteXmlFiles>
                    <properties>
                        <property>
                          <name>testnames</name>
                          <value>${testNames}</value>
                        </property>
             </properties>

        </configuration>
    </plugin>
```

then run as : `mvn test -DsuiteXmlFile=src/test/resources/xmlfilename` -DtestNames=group1

Configure based on your project structure for the suitefile..

Answer (score 0):

Kindly try below command :

To Run Group : `mvn test -Dtests=group1,group2`

To Run Class : `mvn test -Dtest=classname`

Comment: If I try mvn test -Dtests=group1 test. All tests are running. FYI I haven't defined any group name in test file. I have mentioned only in testing.xml

Comment: No. All tests defined in testing.xml are ran.

Comment: Can you show me code where you have assigned group to classes?

Comment: I made assignment in testing.xml only not anywhere.

Comment: Seems you are doing something wrong. Did you created Maven POM xml?